# update records in oracle8i database where we cannot use regex

Tags: sql, oracle8i

I have a task in hand where I need to update phone numbers format of around 200 records. The current format is

`xwz@gmail.com,04163304166@redcoal.com`

The new format should be

`xwz@gmail.com,+614163304166@redcoal.com`

I tried to use `regex` but oracle 8i doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: Could you instead improve your schema design and store these in separate columns? CSV data in a single relational database column is a bad design smell

Comment: @Phil Yes you are right but its a legacy application and changing the schema will trigger the change on the application side as well which we don't want.

Comment: You might want to put that information front-and-centre in your question so you don't gather downvotes, etc for _"bad design"_ (which happens all too often)

Comment: You can possibly use PLSQL with INSTR and SUBSTR functions. It really depends on your data format.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a really bad data format -- storing multiple values in a string.  But, you can use `replace()`, at least for the example you have given:

```
select replace(col, ',0', ',+61')
from t;
```

I would check that this does what you want.  In the end, the query might look like:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, ',0', ',+61')
    where col like '%,0';
```